# add the event to imageview during tableview scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented the tableview with custom cell. There are image view on cell and I had added gesture recognizer to it. But when I click on imageview for firing some event it goes to that method with number as I have scrolled the table view. Suppose I scrolled the tableview 5 times then it imageview also fires the method 5 times.

This is the code:

```
{
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 200.0);
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [cell.image1 setTag:indexPath.row*2];
    [cell.image2 setTag:indexPath.row*2+1];

    NSString *pathimage1 =[[aroundmearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSString *filePath1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pathimage1];
    NSString *pathimage2=[[aroundmearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2+1]objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSString *filePath2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pathimage2];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlefirstTap:)];
    tap1.delegate=self;
    tap1.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [cell.image1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
    [tap1 release];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlesecondTap:)];
    tap2.delegate=self;
    tap2.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [cell.image2 addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
    [tap2 release];
    [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath1]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    [cell.image2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath2]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

}
return cell;
```

Comment: once check by writing ur code in (cell== nil) block

Comment: @murali I checked that already. But by putting the code in block it shows the same images again and again.

Comment: Please put your code in your question, instead of linking to a pastebin.  I have fixed it for you this time.

Comment: @MinkleGarg instead of writing code in outside of "cell==nil",please write inside of the if condition and check...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you added gesture recognizer in the outside of `cell == nil` condition.
`TableView` will invoke `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method whenever scrolling. So you can avoid this by adding gesture recognizer inside of `cell == nil` condition.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableViewCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tblNameList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)  {
        NSArray* nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlefirstTap:)];
        tap1.delegate=self;
        tap1.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
        [cell.image1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
        [tap1 release];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlesecondTap:)];
        tap2.delegate=self;
        tap2.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
        [cell.image2 addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
        [tap2 release];
    }

    [cell.image1 setTag:indexPath.row*2];
    [cell.image2 setTag:indexPath.row*2+1];

    NSString *pathimage1 = [[aroundmearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSString *filePath1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pathimage1];
    NSString *pathimage2 = [[aroundmearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2+1]objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSString *filePath2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pathimage2];

    [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath1]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    [cell.image2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath2]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I tried this too but it makes the scrolling hard by loaded the nib.

Answer (score 1):

// Try this..

//in .h

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1[100];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2[100];
```

//in .m

```
{
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 200.0);
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [cell.image1 setTag:indexPath.row*2];
    [cell.image2 setTag:indexPath.row*2+1];

    if(!tap1[indexPath.row])
{
    tap1[indexPath.row] = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlefirstTap:)]autorelease];
    tap1.delegate=self;
    tap1.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [cell.image1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
}
    if(!tap2[indexPath.row])
{
    tap2[indexPath.row] =
    [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlesecondTap:)]autorelease];
    tap2.delegate=self;
    tap2.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [cell.image2 addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
}
    [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[aroundmearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]objectForKey:@"image"]]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    [cell.image2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[aroundmearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2+1]objectForKey:@"image"]]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

}
return cell;
```

Comment: other wise create UITapGestureRecognizer in custom cell only and give addtarget in cellforrowatindexpath. This will be the permanent solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

//try this..this code will helpfull for you as per memory management..

//in custom cell..

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        [self addSubview: image1];

        tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
        tap1.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
        [image1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
    }
}
```

//in .m

```
{
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 200.0);
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [cell.image1 setTag:indexPath.row*2];
    [cell.image2 setTag:indexPath.row*2+1];

    [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[aroundmearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]objectForKey:@"image"]]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    [cell.image2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[aroundmearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2+1]objectForKey:@"image"]]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        [cell.tap1 addTarget:self action:@selector(handlefirstTap:)];
        [cell.tap2 addTarget:self action:@selector(handlesecondTap:)];
}
return cell;
```